# jQuery Ajax post to create PDF

Tags: jquery, asp.net, pdf

My Problem is when I clicked button call "Print" it will get data from table and send ajax via jQuery to call page method to create pdf but nothing happen.

This is my code

Client

```
function Print(button) {
                var arrDTO = new Array();
                var printButton = $(button);
                var $targetTable = printButton.parent().parent().find('table');
                var $tr = $targetTable.find('tbody tr');

                for (var i = 0; i < $tr.length; i++) {
                    var newObj = {};
                    var td = $($tr[i]).find('td');
                    newObj.BugID = $(td[0]).find('a').html().trim();
                    newObj.Title = $(td[2]).find('a').html().trim();
                    newObj.HouseName = $(td[3]).html().trim();
                    newObj.RoomName = $(td[4]).html().trim();
                    newObj.ThePersonResponsibleName = $(td[5]).html().trim();
                    newObj.FAGName = $(td[6]).html().trim(); 
                    newObj.CompanyName = $(td[7]).html().trim();
                    newObj.Reminders = $(td[8]).html().trim();
                    newObj.Delayed = $(td[9]).html().trim();
                    newObj.Appendix = $(td[10]).html().trim();
                    newObj.MoreInfo = $(td[11]).html().trim();
                    newObj.DeadLine = $(td[12]).html().trim();
                    newObj.Comment = $(td[13]).find('input[type=\"text\"]').val().trim();
                    newObj.Retention = $(td[14]).find('label').html().trim();
                    newObj.Discount = $(td[15]).html().trim();
                    newObj.Balance = $(td[16]).html().trim();
                    newObj.StatusName = $(td[17]).html().trim();

                    arrDTO[i] = newObj;

                    //alert('row ' + (i + 1) + ' ' + arrDTO[i].BugID); 
                }

                var DTO = { 'issueType2ViewModel': arrDTO };

                $.ajax({
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": "IssuesType2.aspx/Print",
                    "data": JSON.stringify(DTO),
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "success": function (data) {
                        alert('success');
                        //window.location = "/1.pdf";
                    },
                    "error": function (data) {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                });
            }
```

This is me Server Code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static void Print(Old_App_Code.ViewModel.IssueType2ViewModel[] issueType2ViewModel)
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.Request[
            int projectID = 0;
            int catID = 0;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request["pid"] != null)
            {
                projectID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request["pid"]);

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request["Cat"] != null)
                {
                    catID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request["Cat"]);
                }
            }

                System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\" + "Test.pdf", FileMode.Create);
                Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4_LANDSCAPE, 1, 1, 1, 1);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
                doc.Open();
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
                doc.Close();
                writer.Close();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                "attachment;filename=First PDF document.pdf");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Test.pdf");
        }
```

But nothing happen with this. What wrong with I do?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ajax call, you should at least get success or error.

how about trying to debug your server code.